# EasyClang doesn't find my headers, even though they are installed

Tags: c, clang

I have EasyClang installed on Sublime text and Clang too. I am working on windows, and my headers are in my WSL environment. I have the following settings:

```
{
  "common_flags" : [
    // For simple projects, you can add a folder where your current file is
    "-I$file_path",
    "-IC:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgfc/LocalState/rootfs/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits",
    "-IC:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgfc/LocalState/rootfs/usr/include/c++/7",

  ]
}
```

However, I get the error: `clang: error
error - 'stdio.h' file not found`

Comment: First try compiling a "hello world" program from the command line. If you still have the same error, you have a problem with your clang installation. If not, you have a problem with your sublime text configuration.

Comment: @n.m. I can do gcc with this or hello world. I am using my windows clang installation, because I'm not sure there is a way to run sublime text on windows with a linux clang installation

Comment: gcc is not clang so I don't see how is this relevant.

Comment: @n.m. Alright, clang shows the same error when compiling hello world. What can I do now?

Comment: Wipe and reinstall it properly I guess. There's more than one way to run clang on windows, I usually install msys2 and install clang from there. I see you are using Linux paths from your WSL install in your configuration. Don't do that. If you want to compile for Linux, either compile *on* Linux, or use proper cross-compilation tools. You shoud never just steal an include path from a foreign OS.

Comment: @n.m. So should I instead try installing a compiler on windows itself?

Comment: Are you trying to compile on windows for linux?

Comment: I am usually compiling via g++/gcc on WSL, however as I need clang on windows I have now installed cygwin and g++/gcc on windows too.

Comment: Cygwin is usually not a good idea for windows development. It's fine if you need to quickly port a Unix program with minimum effort, but I have no idea about how this is connected to "I need clang on windows". Why do you think you need clang and not any other compiler? What do you need it *for*? In any case, an include path from WSL is just plain wrong.

Comment: @n.m. I need it so that I can use sublimetext's easyclang plugin :) i wont be compiling anything, but the plugin isn't working

Comment: I guess the easiest way to get it working is with msys2 as I said earlier. Another way is to install clang as a Visual Studio add-on.